# Power - BI : Columns based on indirect column to display in Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI and working on a special requirement and need some help.

I am working on a report with fields from multiple tables - which are connected with proper relationships. I have to use those columns and display the report based on some calculations and at the same time display what's the last value reported against those calculations.

Some sample structure as below. Here Measure-1 and Measure-2 have some calculations on some certain dates. Challenge here is I need to display the report for the latest date along with the Measure-1 & 2 for all the dates combined ( More of Sum of that calculation on all dates) and same calculation on last available date.

| Emp Id (Emp Table) | Emp Name (Emp Table) | Emp Dept (Dept Table) | Last Pay Date (Dates table) | Measure-1 | Measure-2 | Latest Measure-1 | Latest Measure-2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emp Id-1 | Name | Dept-1 | Date-1 | Aggregated calculation for all the dates | Aggregated calculation for all the dates | (Measure-1 value from recent date) | (Measure-2 value from recent date) |
| Emp Id-2 | Name | Dept-2 | Date-2 | Aggregated calculation for all the dates | Aggregated calculation for all the dates | (Measure-1 value from recent date) | (Measure-2 value from recent date) |

```
Measure-1 = SUM(Sal_Table.Base_Sal) + (SUM(Bonus_Table.Variable_Pay)+SUM(Bonus_Table.Increment_Amount))

Measure-2 = (Measure-1) - (Tax_Table.Tax_Amt)
```

Challenge here is I need to display the SUM of all dates and the values on recent update in same table.

Was able to add those measures with the calculations from across the tables. But no idea on how to get the same on the latest date. Any inputs on how to achieve this in Power BI.

Comment: This contains an example of a DAX calculation that shows a measure value for a specific date. You'll need to adapt to whatever you're using https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Calculating-Current-Period/td-p/1305996

Comment: Update your question with the code you have used for measure-1 and measure-2.

Comment: Updated with the measures I was using. @Sam Nseir

Answer (score 0):

It could look something like this, modify as needed:

```
Latest Measure-1 = 
  var fSal = TOPN(1, Sal_Table, [DateColumnOfSal], DESC)
  var fBonus = TOPN(1, Bonus_Table, [DateColumnOfBonus], DESC)
  return
    CALCULATE( MAX(Sal_Table[Base_Sal]), fSal ) +
    CALCULATE( MAX(Bonus_Table[Variable_Pay]), fBonus ) +
    CALCULATE( MAX(Bonus_Table[Increment_Amount]), fBonus )
```